# Can you prove that a seeming growing sequence goes to infinity?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I was given this problem from my brother he told me to prove that a sequence goes to infinity.

It starts at 21. You write 21 in hereditary base 2 notation like this $2^{2^2}+2^2+1$.

He told me to change all the 2's into the next prime number then subtract 1. $3^{3^3}+3^3$ or 7625597485014. Then he told me to change all the 3's into the next prime number and subtract 1. $5^{5^5}+5^4+4\times5^3+4\times5^2+4\times5^1+4$ or $1.9 × 10^{2184}$. And he asked me to prove that the sequence of numbers goes to infinity. But I have no clue how. It's clear that it does.

Can you prove that this sequence goes to infinity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@martycohen Here is a better answer to this problem as Marty Cohen had said it doesn't diverge and here is the proof.

here is a thing you need to know a ever shrinking list of infinite ordinals will always go down to 0 in a finite time.

you start with $2^{2^2}+2^2+1$

change all twos into omega the first order type infinity $w^{w^w}+w^w+1$
then take the next one on the list and change all the next prime number 3 into omegas

$w^{w^w}+w^w$ it shrank

the next one $w^{w^w}+w^4+4×w^3+4×w^2+4×w^1+4$ it shrank again and will always because you can't make the powers any bigger then they are and you always subtract 1.

Answer (score 3):

This is known
as a Goodstein sequence.
Even though the terms
grow quite large
(an understatement),
they eventually decrease
and go to zero.

But, as they say,
don't try this at home.

Two references.

https://googology.wikia.org/wiki/Goodstein_sequence

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem

Comment: Usual presentations of Goodstein's Theorem involve raising the base by one at each iteration, not raising it to the next prime. This doesn't make a difference?

Comment: Don't know, but this is definitely a good point. I would have to examine the proof to see if this change still allows the result to hold. Don't think I will. I will upvote your comment, though.

Comment: @martycohen someone shared the full proof can you make sure makes sense? it seems to.